# Changing Woocommerce Mini cart content background color

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In my WooCommerce website's menu bar, there is a cart icon, and when I hover the cart icon, I get a **dark background color** for the mini cart content.

The link to my shop is http://www.nexus-ht.tk.

I am trying to change this color in the theme css file but I still don't find the way to do it.

How can I change the background color on the mini cart content?

Comment: Use the chrome inspector to look at the CSS for the element, and it will tell you the class name. Then find that in your CSS files and changes it, or do an override in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add this CSS rule at the end of your theme `style.css` file. Here I change the background color to red (you can replace red by your desired color):

```css
ul.shopping-cart-dropdown{
    background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

This should work. you will get this:

[image]